# VueJS HTML-Webpack-Plugin causing a blank page

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, html-webpack-plugin

I am attempting to create a VueJS app that I can build into a single HTML file (with all the JS and CSS inline) to be used similarly to a native app. The user just opens the *.html file in their browser and is able to use it.

I've found two Webpack plugins for this, but it's not working correctly.

Webpack Plugins:

- [html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin)
- [webpack-inline-modern-source-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-inline-modern-source-plugin)

Here's my issue:

- Created a fresh Vue project, using Vue CLI 3
- Ran `npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin webpack-inline-modern-source-plugin`
- Created a `vue.config.js` file in the root directory with the code below
- Attempted to run `npm run serve` to test if the site still works, but I get a blank white page with the error `[Error] [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app`
- If I remove the items in the `plugins` Array, it works normally

Here is my `vue.config.js` file:

```
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
let WebpackInlineMordernSourcePlugin = require("webpack-inline-modern-source-plugin");

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inlineSource: ".(js|css)$"
      }),
      new WebpackInlineMordernSourcePlugin()
    ]
  }
};
```

**node**: `12.12.0`

**npm**: `6.11.3`

Hopefully I'm just missing something and these plugins work fine.